A Venndredi Special!
Another Venn based puzzle from me.  The three overlapping ellipses form seven curved regions.  Your task is to place exactly one tile per region, so that the four tiles in any one ellipse can solve the corresponding clue!


The Groups are:

 YOU TUBE: CA TH ET ER (u shaped-tube).
FISHERMAN’S INSTRUMENT: CA ST AN ET (musical instrument a wordplay on ‘cast a net’).
TOO MANY ACTORS: OV ER CA ST.


